# FOR /F with spaces doesn't work

Tags: windows, batch

```
FOR /f %%F IN ('dir /b /s "%DeploymentDirectory%\Run.*.dll"') DO ECHO %%F
```

The problem is that the paths returned by `dir` have spaces and only a part of the path is displayed. How do I fix so that it displays the full path?

Answer (score 8):

You need to set the delimiters used to split the line into tokens so that spaces aren't included. Something like "delims=?" Right after the /f. Just use a character that's illegal in filenames (? and * are good candidates)

```
FOR /F "delims=?" %%F in ('dir /b /s "%Dir%\Run.*.dll"') DO ECHO "%%F"
```

Just remember to put double quotes around the %%F in your actual commands as the expanded variable will have spaces in it as well.

Comment: You don't need to find an illegal character, you can just put the delims at the end of the options string with no delimiters: `FOR /F "usebackq delims=" [...]`.

Comment: Note that both `?` and `*` can appear with Unicode file names and Raster fonts for the console window (which will convert Unicode as best as possible into the OEM codepage but inserts `?` if impossible). So heed Bacon's advice and just use no delimiters.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need to iterate over `dir`'s output at all, here? Simply using

```
for /r %%F in ("%DeploymentDirectory%\Run.*.dll")
```

doesn't suffice?

Comment: very good! I'll adjust my bat's with that :)

Answer (score 2):

set the delims to be start and end of line

```
for /f "delims=" %%F
```

etc

Comment: That's just setting no delimiter at all. `for /f` parses line-wise, so you *always* have a new loop iteration at the next line, regardless of how you set the delimiters.