# Spaces in filenames, symantics as usual

Tags: windows-7, grammar, smart-quotes

hello im having an issue with spaces in the %%a attribute inside a Batch FOR.

if i have some files in a folder

```
yoda jedi.tif
jaba king.tif
solo smug.tif
```

the following code,

```
@echo off & setlocal
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b /s "R:\Scans\Epson_v550\*.tif"') do (
echo This was received: %%a
)
```

results in output of:

```
This was received: yoda
This was received: jaba
This was received: solo
```

How can i restructure it so %%a includes the full file name with spaces from %%a?

id like this result:

```
This was received: yoda jedi.tif
This was received: jaba king.tif
This was received: solo smug.tif
```

but even when i try,

```
echo This was received: "%%a"
```

i still only get back the word before the space. its like %%a is being lopped off at the first space during assignment. Please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FOR /F with spaces doesn't work](https://superuser.com/questions/274646/for-f-with-spaces-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think I've figured it out, inclusion of the line "delims=" seems to have rectified the space-in-file-names issue.

```
@echo off & setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /s "R:\Scans\Epson_v550\*.tif"') do (
echo This was received: %%a
)
```

This works as desired resulting in:

```
This was received: yoda jedi.tif
This was received: jaba king.tif
This was received: solo smug.tif
```

if

```
yoda jedi.tif
jaba king.tif
solo smug.tif
```

exist in the specified folder.